# Docker why isn't $USER environment variable set

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu

I'm doing a simple docker build where the image runs a script that assumes `$USER` is set, like it normally is in a bash shell.

However, `$USER` is not set, when using `/bin/bash` or `/bin/bash --login`.  Very easy to demonstrate using the latest `ubuntu`

```
$ docker run -t -i ubuntu:latest
root@1dbeaefd6cd4:/# echo $USER

root@1dbeaefd6cd4:/# exit

$ docker run -t -i ubuntu:latest /bin/bash --login
root@d2728a8188a5:/# echo $USER

root@1dbeaefd6cd4:/# exit
```

However, if in the shell I `su -l root`, then `$USER` is set.

```
root@d2728a8188a5:/# su -l root
root@d2728a8188a5:~# echo $USER
root
root@d2728a8188a5:~# exit
```

I'm aware I could add `ENV USER=root` to the `Dockerfile`, but I'm trying to avoid hard-coding the value.

Does anyone have a suggestion of why this might be happening?  I'm asking mostly out of curiosity to understand what's happening when Docker starts `bash`.  It's clearly not exactly like a login shell and the `--login` option doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The only environment variables documented to be set](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) are `$HOME`, `$HOSTNAME`, `$PATH`, and (maybe) `$TERM`.  (A `docker build` `RUN` step internally does the equivalent of `docker run`.)  If you need other variables set you can use the `ENV` directive.

Typically in a Dockerfile there's no particular need to make path names or user names configurable, since these live in an isolated space separate from the host.  For instance, it's extremely common to put "the application" in `/app` even though that's not a standard FHS path.  It's considered a best practice, though infrequently done, to set up some non-root user to actually run the application and use a `USER` directive late in a Dockerfile.  In all of these cases you know what the username actually is; it's not any sort of parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Docker environment variables docs.  That eluded me.

Comment: in my container i have configured a new user and when i exec with `bash --login` i get the USER env var set. so i updated my entrypoint.sh shebang to also have the `/bin/bash --login` which fixed the USER env var not being set when the application was starting.

Answer (score 7):

According to https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html:

> The variables `$ENV`, `$LOGNAME`, `$MAIL`, `$TERM`, `$USER`, and `$USERNAME` are not Bash builtins. These are, however, often set as environmental variables in one of the Bash or login startup files.

Also as pointed out in this Unix&Linux SE answer  [Who sets $USER and $USERNAME environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76369/297058):

> There's no rule. Some shells like `tcsh` or `zsh` set `$LOGNAME`. `zsh` sets `$USER`.
>
> It may be set by some things that log you in like `login` (as invoked by `getty` when login on a terminal and sometimes by other things like `in.rlogind`), `cron`, `su`, `sudo`, `sshd`, `rshd`, graphical login managers or may not.
>
> […]

So in the context of a clean environment within a Docker container, you may rather want to rely on `whoami` or `id`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu
root@7f6191875c62:/# whoami
root
root@7f6191875c62:/# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@7f6191875c62:/# id -u -n
root
```

Comment: Thanks for the background.  The `whoami` and `id -u -n` commands are good alternatives - thanks for listing them.

Answer (score 0):

Try running "/bin/bash -i" which will force interactive mode and execute the .profile where environment variables are usually stored.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That doesn't work.  Same result.