# Why is it chown when running: missing operand after `/usr/local/hadoop/logs'

Tags: dockerfile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8F81.png)Dockerfile build successfly, however, I used ocker run -it --hostname hadoop1 --name hadoop hadoop_v1.0 and there was a try `chown --help' for more information,I checked all the logs under /usr/local/hadoop/logs and they all reported an error,The container can also run normally

This is a dockerfile for building hadoop.
The chown command is used in the dockerfile in the following places:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJW3h.png)

```
RUN chmod 600 ${ROOT_HOME}/.ssh/config && \
    chown root:root ${ROOT_HOME}/.ssh/config && \
    chown root:root /etc/bootstrap.sh && \
    chmod 700 /etc/bootstrap.sh && \
    chmod +x $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/*-env.sh && \
    adduser hdpuser && \
    echo 'hdpuser:hdppassword' | chpasswd && \
    usermod -aG wheel hdpuser && \
    echo "%wheel        ALL=(ALL)       ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because USER env var is not set in docker which is used sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh script. But in the case of the hadoop you should set env var HADOOP_IDENT_STRING to the desired user, the one that is excuting process inside container.

See [Docker why isn't $USER environment variable set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411218/docker-why-isnt-user-environment-variable-set)